# Можно ли привязать панель к низу страницы?

Tags: ipad, cocoa, ios, iphone

Нужно панель UIView привязать к низу страницы. Проблема в том, что при разном положении устройства у нас будет разные x, y. Нашел решение: при изменении ориентации пересчитывать координаты и заново устанавливать setFrame. Есть ли какое-то простое решение без подобных фокусов?

Comment: можно как-то более понятно и подробней объяснить?

Comment: Я поставил UIView внизу экрана. После поворота устройства панель остается на своем месте, т.е. получается уже не внизу. Нужно чтобы эта панель была привязана к низу, как в Java при BorderLayout - PAGE_END.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте разные режимы автопозиционирования. В IB это третья вкладка, если я правильно помню. Программно это делается

```
UIView *view = ...//инициализация
view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

Используйте нужную комбинацию. В примере панель крепится к краям левый, правый, низ и при этом меняет размеры по ширине.